Is the Upper Domination Number in $G^2$ $\leq$ the Lower Domination Number in $G$?
Given an unweighted graph $G$, the upper domination number $\Gamma(G)$ is defined as the maximum size of a minimal dominating set of vertices in $G$.
The (lower) domination number $\gamma(G)$ is defined as the minimum size of a dominating set of vertices.
$G^2$ is a graph with the same set of vertices as $G$ and an edge between two vertices iff there is a path of length at most 2 between them in $G$
The problem is to prove or disprove $\Gamma(G^2)$ $\leq$ $\gamma(G)$.
I currently know that $\alpha(G^2)$ $\leq$ $\gamma(G)$ and $\alpha(G^2)$ $\leq$ $\Gamma(G^2)$, where $\alpha(G^2)$ is the independence number,  but I have no further idea to solve this problem. Is there any proof to prove $\Gamma(G^2)$ $\leq$ $\gamma(G)$ or any counterexample?

Take a complete graph minus a perfect matching for $G$

Are you very sure of the notation? Most people write $\alpha(G)$ for the independence number.

@MishaLavrov Sorry for the confusion. You are correct.$\alpha(G)$ is independence number, and $\gamma(G)$ is domination number.

@caduk Take $K_6$ for instance, Let $G = K_6 - M$, where $M$ is a perfect matching for $K_6$, then $G^2$ is still $K_6$, so $\Gamma(G^2) = 1$

@Sorry, I mixed up the inequality. What about a ladder graph with two additional vertices, each linked to all the vertices of a side rail? The domination number is $2$, but if you take one vertex out of 2 on one side rail, you get a big upper domination number.

@caduk Your graph works! In your graph $G$, $\gamma(G)$ is always 2, no matter the length of the rail. However, $\Gamma(G^2)$ can be arbitrarily large if we increase the rail length and always pick the nodes on one side rail as the dominating set. Therefore, $\Gamma(G^2) \leq \gamma(G)$ is not correct. Thank you for your brilliant answer!
